# Match array keys and set its value to result array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have set of two arrays, As showed in **image** *Arr1* and *Arr2*.

Both array having data with keys like 1, 2, 3,......

I want resultant array by matching these keys and create new array with **keys** of first array *Arr1* and **values** are values of second array *Arr2*

Also check condition if all the values from *Arr2* are empty then don't consider that array for result.

If this is not helpful let me know.

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: [array_combine()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) sounds like the function that you're looking for, probably followed by an [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove any empty values

Comment: ok, Thanx, but what about the rest